# Pagenation code stops at page 2

Tags: java, selenium

Below code stops running at the page 2, I have 5 to 6 pages, each page contains 10 records...

```
public void pagenate() throws Exception { 
    page.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='leftnav-query-history']")).click(); 
    List pagination = page.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='next']/a"));       
    System.out.println(pagination.size()); 
    if(pagination.size()>0) { 
          System.out.println("pagination exists"); 
          for(int i=0; i<pagination.size(); i++)
      {          
       pagination.get(i).click();
            page.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']/a")); 
     }
    }else {
           System.out.println("pagination not exists");
           }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you are taking count of next link on page, which should be only 1. Total pages should be counted in some different manner. Please provide the html of your pagination area.

Comment: hi husam, below tags for pagination area <div class="pull-right">
<div id="pagination" class="pagination" style="">
<ul>
<li id="prev" class="prev" style="display: none;">
<li id="p1" class="active" style="display: inline;">
<li id="p2" style="display: inline;">
<li id="p3" style="display: inline;">
<li id="p4" style="display: inline;">
<li id="p5" style="display: inline;">
<li id="next" class=" next ">
</ul>
</div>

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```
public void pagenate(WebElement page) throws Exception { 
    page.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='leftnav-query-history']")).click(); 
    do{
        page.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='next']/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);// You can Waitfor some element on next page to load or change, to improve performance.
    } while (page.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='next']/a")).size()>0 && page.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='next']/a")).isDisplayed());
}
```

Comment: Error displayed after above code execution,                                                            "SKIPPED: pagenate
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method pagenate requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation."

Comment: You need to modify the function as per your code, the WebElement variable *page* is parameter in this function, you should either pass this while calling function or remove it and handle it as you have handled in your original function.